# Create SharePoint Role Definition

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, 2019

I am developing an application for SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint online.

I need to create a custom role definition via REST API. the only thing I have found is `/_api/web/roledefinitions` but only to consult them.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code I tried to create a role definition using SharePoint REST API:

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="createField()"> Create Role Definition </button>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createRoleDefinition() {
        var roleDefinitionEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/roledefinitions";

        $.ajax({
            url: roleDefinitionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.RoleDefinition' },
                'BasePermissions': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.BasePermissions' }, 'High': '176', 'Low': '138612801' },
                'Description': 'New Permission Level Description',
                'Name': 'New Permission Level',
                'Order': 180
            }),
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Role Definition created successfully");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Official documentation**: [RoleDefinitionCollection resource - Create a role definition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)#request-examples-5)

**Additional references**:

1. [Get SharePoint Role Definition ID's](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-sharepoint-role-definition-ids/)

Comment: An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified.

I'm getting the above error, I'm moreover trying in power automate