# How to change access level of SharePoint Group by Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, timer-jobs, power-automate, modern-team-site

I'm using Modern experience in SharePoint Online.
I would like to change SharePoint Group's access level regularly.
So I want to ask how to change access level of SharePoint Group by Power Automate.

I would be very grateful if you have any suggestion or idea for even the smallest things.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to review, remove, and add new permission to a SPO Group using Power Automate. Of course, based on your requirements, you might also need [Parse JSON], [Apply to each] actions in your flow.

1. **Review** current roles/permission level of a SPO group. In the case SharePoint group id is 141

[image]

2. **Remove** all current roles from that group.

[image]

3. **Add** new role/permission to the group. In this case, it's adding Full Control

[image]

RoleDefids:
1073741829, Full Control
1073741827, Contribute
1073741826, Read

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have the list of RoleDefids numbers?

Comment: You can get it by a **GET** method using **/_api/web/roledefinitions?$filter=Hidden eq false**. In the output, you can find the properties of **"Description": "Has full control.",        
        "Id": 1073741829,
        "Name": "Full Control"**

Comment: Thanks you very much. understood.
How do you create the contents of Parse to JSON? I want to use it as a reference for other Flows.

Comment: Usually, when you get data from some source, say SPO using [Get Items] action, it would return items as a collection. You would first run the flow and analyze the output. Then add [Parse JSON] action. As input to [Parse JSON], use the [Body] from the previous step and to generate schema, use the output from [Get items] (copy and paste) to generate schema. Check out [article](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2017/11/23/using-json-in-microsoft-flow-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you very much Matiur.

Comment: Hi Matiur, Thank you for your always support. It would be appreciated if you could answer this question.　https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289540/how-to-edit-permission-level-of-sharepoint-using-power-automate/289572#289572

Comment: Sure.. will take a look into it. Looks like changing *Permissions* to customize a permission level. It definitely is going to be a REST API call. Let you know later today.

Comment: I am so grateful to you. I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Did you come up with a good idea?

Comment: I found a REST API POST method to create custom role definitions. However, I couldn't make it work from **Power Automate**. You can check it out [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285691/create-sharepoint-role-definition). I will let you know if I eventually make it work from PA.