# How to edit Permission Level of SharePoint using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-permissions, modern-team-site, custom-permission-level

I'm using Modern experience in SharePoint Online.

I would like to edit Permission Level checkbox (List Permissions, Site Permissions, Personal Permissions) using Power Automate.
[image]

So if possible I'd like to see sample for Power Automate.

I would be very grateful if you have any idea for even the smallest things.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an action in Power Automate to create or change an existing permission level but you do have access to the [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/working-with-send-sp-http-request) action in Power Automate. You may be able to use this action to make the appropriate REST API call to create your custom permission level.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following article.

https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/use-power-automate-flow-to-change-sharepoint-group-permission-level/

For further assistance, you could go to [Microsoft Power Automate Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity).

Comment: The question is asking how to edit the permission level rather than applying it to groups.